# What's the right way to fix Windows Memory Compression causing CPU usage spikes?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, performance, freeze

By inspecting CPU usage, as seen in the next graph:

[image]

You can see that memory compressions is causing high spikes in CPU usage. It's so bad that the computer freezes every now and then for a few seconds. I'm not sure how important memory compression is, and whether I should just accept this freeze. What's the right thing to do to solve this problem?

Comment: How much memory do you have? How much are you using? Memory compression happening regularly in the first place suggests that your system is memory limited and you should look at upgrading that first.

Comment: @Mokubai I have 32 GB of memory. I'm using like 18 GB out of it. What kind of upgrade are you talking about?

Comment: I see that memory compression takes 6.64% of the CPU, which is not much. But if you're worried about the fact that it's at all happening, check the memory allocation of your programs, to see if one uses too much. You may use Task Manager or Resource Monitor for that.

Comment: @harrymc Perhaps that's just maxing out one core? I'm not sure how process explorer does the counting. But the more important thing is the freezes I get during these spikes.

Comment: The memory compression might not be the cause of the symptoms, but only another symptom. You need to better understand what happens during the freezes.

Comment: Well, I'll keep an eye on it. But you see there are two big spikes in the chart, both froze the computer, and both were from memory compression.

Comment: I find it unlikely that 6.64% of the CPU froze the computer.